# Parse JSON from GET response when headers are present

Tags: php, json, curl, http-get, servlet-3.0

I am trying to [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) the response I receive from a GET request to my server-side API but I am getting an empty string back. Would I be right in assuming that because the response contains all the header info that the JSON decoder cant cope? This is the full response I'm getting from my server:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.0.5
Date: Sun, 18 Mar 2012 19:44:43 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0; JBossAS-6
Content-Length: 97

{"pid":"162000798ab8481eaeb2b867e10f8849","uuid":"973b8722c75a4cacb9fd2316517587bb"}
```

Do I need to remove the headers in my servlet before I send the response to the client?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, `json_decode` must be passed *just* the JSON data to decode. Since you are using curl, you can simply configure the request to not return the headers to you with something like

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
```

**Update:** if you need the headers for earlier processing then the above won't cut it. However, you can remove them easily at any point by taking advantage of the fact that there will be a double-newline "delimiter" between the header and body of the response. Using `explode` like this will then isolate the body:

```
list(,$body) = explode("\n\n", $response, 2);
```

Comment: I need to send headers in the request but remove them from the response so I can parse only the JSON. Won't curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); remove header info from the request also?

Comment: @travega: Yes, that will not work then. I have updated the answer to suggest a solution for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
json_decode(@file_get_contents('php://input'), true)
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON response cannot be decoded with the header. Therefore you have to disable header in your response using the following code:

```
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
```

in order to use any info in the header you can use `curl_getinfo` function. For example to get http status code, use:

```
curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)
```

For more options refer to the get info manual here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php

Answer (score 0):

To throw away all headers:

```
   $postResponse=json_decode(substr($postResponse,strpos($postResponse,'{')), true);
```